# What does the registerNatives() method do?

Tags: java, c, object, methods, java-native-interface

In java, what does the private static method `registerNatives()` of the Object class do?

Comment: Ah of course, I hadn't considered the JNI aspects... Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The other answers are technically correct, but not very useful for someone with no JNI experience. :-)

Normally, in order for the JVM to find your native functions, they have to be named a certain way. e.g., for `java.lang.Object.registerNatives`, the corresponding C function is named `Java_java_lang_Object_registerNatives`. By using `registerNatives` (or rather, the JNI function `RegisterNatives`), you can name your C functions whatever you want.

Here's the associated C code (from OpenJDK 6):

```
static JNINativeMethod methods[] = {
    {"hashCode",    "()I",                    (void *)&JVM_IHashCode},
    {"wait",        "(J)V",                   (void *)&JVM_MonitorWait},
    {"notify",      "()V",                    (void *)&JVM_MonitorNotify},
    {"notifyAll",   "()V",                    (void *)&JVM_MonitorNotifyAll},
    {"clone",       "()Ljava/lang/Object;",   (void *)&JVM_Clone},
};

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_java_lang_Object_registerNatives(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls)
{
    (*env)->RegisterNatives(env, cls,
                            methods, sizeof(methods)/sizeof(methods[0]));
}
```

(Notice that `Object.getClass` is not in the list; it will still be called by the "standard" name of `Java_java_lang_Object_getClass`.) For the functions listed, the associated C functions are as listed in that table, which is handier than writing a bunch of forwarding functions.

Registering native functions is also useful if you are embedding Java in your C program and want to link to functions within the application itself (as opposed to within a shared library), or the functions being used aren't otherwise "exported", since these would not normally be found by the standard method lookup mechanism. Registering native functions can also be used to "rebind" a native method to another C function (useful if your program supports dynamically loading and unloading modules, for example).

I encourage everybody to read the [JNI book](http://www.informit.com/store/java-native-interface-programmers-guide-and-specification-9780201325775), which talks about this and much more. :-)

Comment: You wrote fully decorated JNI function name, which makes it confusing: is `Java_java_lang_Object_registerNatives` called by VM automatically, or c/c++ code has to call that function and there is no need for all that java gobblygook

Comment: @Pavel By default, a native method `methodName` in class `fully.qualified.ClassName` is searched under the C name `Java_fully_qualified_ClassName_methodName` (which your C-side code must export). You can call `JNIEnv`'s `RegisterNatives` method to override this linkage. In other words, if you don't use `RegisterNatives` first, "all that java gobblygook" [sic] is required.

Comment: Ah, ok, so by exporting only 1 function `Java_java_lang_Object_registerNatives` I can actually link all my JNI stuff by checking value of `cls`.  I missed the part that registerNatives is actually part of java itself. So... when some class is about to be used, what's the order of actions that JVM uses to link natives? It seems that if natives's aren't registered yet (from c/c++), then JVM checks for all these exported names, if they aren't present then it tries to use Object.registerNatives (or the other way around?). By the way, the jni book link is dead.

Comment: If you haven't called `RegisterNatives`, and the exported names aren't available, then you will get a runtime error when you try to call the method. `Object.registerNatives` is an internal method of OpenJDK's implementation of `java.lang.Object`, called from its class initialiser, and its sole purpose is to register the native methods that pertain to `java.lang.Object` only. If you are writing your own native library, it's up to you to register your library's native methods yourself (should you wish to).

Comment: best answer I've ever seen

Answer (score 15):

What might be slightly confusing is that the code shown for `java.lang.Object.registerNatives` in a previous answer is just an *example* of how to register native functions.  This is the code that (in the implementation of OpenJDK) registers native functions for class Object.  To register native functions for your own class, you must call the JNI function `RegisterNatives` from the native code in your own library.  This might sound a bit circular, but there are a couple ways to break the loop.

1. Follow the example of this implementation of class Object:

   a. In your Java class, declare a native method (preferably static) named `registerNatives` (or any other name. it doesn't matter).

   b. In your native code, define a function named `Java_<your fully qualified class name>_registerNatives`, which contains a call to the JNI function `RegisterNatives`.

   c. Make sure that in your Java code, your Java `registerNatives` method is called prior to any calls to other native methods.

OR

2. Use `JNI_OnLoad`

   a. In your native library define a function `jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved)`.  In the body of this function, call the JNI function `RegisterNatives`.

   b. The Java VM will automatically look for and call `JNI_OnLoad` when your native library is loaded by `System.loadLibrary`, which you should already be calling, probably in a static initializer for your class.  (You get the required `env` pointer by calling the `GetEnv` function in the table that the `vm` pointer points to.)

Answer (score 0):

It is used on such scene :

C or C++ work as host, and Java the JVM as client. (C load `jvm.dll` and use `JNI_CreateJavaVM` to create a JVM)

When java code need to call host's C function,
If you still use jni dll (`System.loadLibrary("foo.dll");`) to bind the native java method, the memory space of dll is not the same as C host. (It still works if the function you called is *host state irrelevant*, but you cannot access host's state values in this way)

Here you need to use `env->RegisterNatives()` at host to inject(bind,expose,export) host's C functions to the JVM.