# Can I invoke a Java program with database call from a cpp program

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have written a `java` program that does some logic check which involves a database call.

I was able to call a simple `cpp` program from java using `JNI` [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50029839/fetching-windows-current-user-with-java-native-interfaces).

How can I do the opposite, i.e Is there a way to call java (with database) from a `cpp` program?

I have `PostgreSQL` database. Any direction would be a great starting point for me.

Thank you for your time. :)

### Edit

Seems like a similar question has a very nice answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374325/is-it-possible-to-make-a-java-jni-which-calls-jdbc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JNI is working from the other way as well cpp -> java http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/index.html

```
/* load and initialize a Java VM, return a JNI interface  
* pointer in env */ 
JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, &env, &vm_args); 

/* invoke the Main.test method using the JNI */ 
jclass cls = env->FindClass("Main"); 
jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "test", "(I)V"); 
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid, 100);
```

Comment: Main concern is will it work with database calls as well?

Comment: why should not work? This one calls the method on java side just integrate with this method your database related stuff.