# Why Object class have static block?

Tags: java, static-block

I want to just know about why Object,String etc. have static{} block at the end.what is the use of static block in Object Class.

Open the cmd prompt and type

```
javap java.lang.Object
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please replace that image with the actual text of the code in question?

Comment: That's just a static initializer, basically...

Comment: @MUSTKEEMMANSURI You just asked that in your question. There's no need to post a comment saying the same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are looking at is just all the method and field declarations. Since the static block is somewhat like a method, you will just see the empty declaration of a static-initalizer.

If you look at the [OpenJDK source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Object.java/#40) for `java.lang.Object` on line 40, the code actually says this

```
public class Object {

     private static native void registerNatives();
     static {
         registerNatives();
     }
```

---

A simple explanation of the static block is that the block only gets called **once**, no matter how many objects of the type you create.

---

If you want more information from the command line, `javap -verbose java.lang.Object` outputs this

```
  static {};
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=0, locals=0, args_size=0
         0: invokestatic  #16                 // Method registerNatives:()V
         3: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 41: 0
        line 42: 3
}
```

---

Or, less verbose `javap -c java.lang.Object`

```
  static {};
    Code:
       0: invokestatic  #16                 // Method registerNatives:()V
       3: return
```

---

If you want to read about what `registerNatives()` does, you can read this post.

[What does the registerNatives() method do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010645/what-does-the-registernatives-method-do)

Comment: I believe this should be added to the javap command description. Doc says "When no options are used, then the javap command prints the package, protected and public fields, and methods of the classes passed to it. The javap command prints its output to stdout." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html or are they implied in one of the items above?

Comment: @ShireResident - A static block is package-private scope defined, I believe. (Since there is no public/private/protected modifier on it)

Comment: I was actually focussed more on the "fields" and "methods". I didn't think static block was considered one of those.

Comment: @ShireResident - not sure I understand. A static block is like a method that runs once when the class is initialized. There are no fields in java.lang.Object

Comment: I was just asking with respect to the terminology because the Oracle docs are usually very specific - just to bolster my understanding. Methods https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4 are defined separately to  "static block" https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7 but then so are constructors.