# NDK build in command line to rebuild my application

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

My project use native library. when I change the package name , I got following error.

code: 
   Native method not found:

```
 com.nooshindroid.yastashir.controller.JNIServer.get_number_of_processors:()I
                                                                            at com.nooshindroid.yastashir.controller.JNIServer.get_number_of_processors(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.nooshindroid.yastashir.controller.JNIServer.runServer(JNIServer.java:27)
                                                                            at com.nooshindroid.yastashir.game.FreebloksActivity.startNewGame(FreebloksActivity.java:520)
                                                                            at com.nooshindroid.yastashir.game.FreebloksActivity$16.onClick(FreebloksActivity.java:774)
                                                                            at com.nooshindroid.yastashir.game.ColorListDialog.onItemClick(ColorListDialog.java:79)
```

when I sreach the net I understand that I must rebuil my JNI folder in command line.
In command line I don't know how to give project path.
I read somewhere that I must write like this .

```
 cd <project>
 $ <ndk>/ndk-build
```

I don't know the steps to do that job.
it show my project path and when I write Dir , it shows me all of things that exist in my folder.
but nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

WHen you use JNI, unless you specify otherwise, the package name is part of the function name it looks for in the C code.  So if you change the package name in Java, you also need to change all your C code JNI function names.

Comment: I know it how can I change it.

Comment: You edit the C files.  If you want to change it permanently so you can change your package name at will you can use registerNatives to override the default mapping, but its a lot of work and you have to maintain that mapping.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010645/what-does-the-registernatives-method-do for a writeup on it

Comment: Because the command doesn't rename the functions for you. It just builds the C code by running the compiler. You have to change it by hand, although it probably wouldn't be difficult to write a custom sed command

Comment: unfortunately, I cant understand how to fix my C code. and the link you mention is so difficult cause I am new with android. please suggest an understandable way

Comment: Learn C. That's basically what you need to fix it. It actually has nothing to do with android it's all about JNI- how java and C talk to one another.

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't solve your problem, you need to edit the C code. Until then building it won't do what you want.

Comment: Would you please tell that for me? I just want to test it.

Comment: You have it in your original post. You need to have the ndk installed and the ndk-build script from it in your path. You may need cygwin or similar Unix shell app if running on Windows.

Comment: it doesn't work. the link that u mention , where I add this method?

Answer (score 0):

As @GabeSechan has said, you need to edit the C or C++ code to match the new package name. When you change the package name, the directory structure changes. If you don't edit the C or C++ code to match, the methods won't be found.

You need to change your JNI methods from

```
Java_com_old_package_name_methodName
```

to

```
Java_com_new_package_name_methodName
```

See the JNI documentation for an [example](https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni.html).

Rebuild your native code after renaming the methods.