# custom JNI method linker or register in Java app

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Is it possible to create custom jni method linker within java application? What exactly I'm trying to do, is to rename or make a links to java native methods under different class path. For example in shared library I have native method declared with class path: com.example.org.SomeClass.someMethod. I would like to invoke this method in a java app from same class, but declared under another package name i.e my.custom.package.name.SomeClass.someMethod

Why I'm trying to do is because I'm using 2 versions of same library in one project which both uses JNI, So I have repacked one version of library with maven shade plugin with a different package name, and I'm getting unsatisfiedlinkerror during invoking JNI method from repacked library

Comment: Does this QA help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1010645 ?

Comment: Not really, since it's requires to hack native code which is unavailable for me. I need to create some kind of wrapper for java JNI native method <-> native code linker, which will be changing class paths between java code and java methods defined inside shared library. Not sure if is it possible under java.